# Supressing query errors SQL

Tags: sql, informix

Someone here know how to supress errors thrown by the ADODB.Connection object when using this query?

```
select count(entry_nbr)  
    from notes  
    where type='A'
```

The error I'm trying to supress is "column ('A') not found in any table of the query", any ideas how?

Comment: That statement should not generate that error. Are you sure you are using single quotes (`'A'`) in your query? The error would make sense if you were using double quotes `"A"`.

Comment: Try, `SELECT count(*) FROM notes AS n where n.type = "A"`

Comment: @Linger `"A"` is a column name. `'A'` is a character literal.

Comment: @Horse the thing is, there are no entries that meet that condition, and that's expected, because on the first run of my program, or after a wipe of the DB I'm expecting the results of that query to help another program realize there is nothing in there and act accordingly.

Comment: **@a_horse_with_no_name**, actually from what I know most databases can use the `'` or `"` interchangeably.  I know the above wuery would work in MySql and Access.

Comment: @FranciscoGarcia. That query would run successfully in Informix and return 0 if there are no records with type='A' (or type="A"). Are you sure that is the complete query you are running?

Comment: @Linger: The SQL standard is pretty clear about that. Identifiers are quoted using `"`, string literals *have* to use `'`. At least Postgres, Oracle, DB2, Firebird, Teradata, HSQLDB, H2, Sybase SQL Anywhere, Apache Derby, Vertica, Greenplum, Cubrid, Mimer SQL, FirstSQL, Amazon Redshift and (I think) Informix do it that way. Anything else is a deviation (in my eyes: violation) of the SQL standard. I'm not surprised that MySQL and Access line up there